# Visual Studio - Add a line break in a label via the designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, label

I have a label that I want to use to show some text.  I want to show a few paragraphs of text.

Is there a way via the designer to make a line break in the text?  (\n\r just shows \n\r)

This is WinForms (actually it is Compact Framework.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Select the **dropdown** next to the label. Then you can just use the `Enter` key to enter line breaks.

Comment: *I never even saw the drop down!* I've been wondering this for years.

Answer (score 13):

You can click the down arrow in the Text property to see a multi-line text field.

In the popup, you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make a newline.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Screenshot of where the **dropdown** is located.]

Dropdown is in the properties section.